# What is the distance from the incenter of the triangle to the vertex B?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, plane-geometry

For reference: The angle $B$ of a triangle $ABC$ measures $16^o$,
its perimeter is $56$ and $AB \cdot BC=600$.
Calculate the distance from the incenter of the triangle to the vertex $B$.(answer:$15\sqrt2$

My progress:

[image]

I know the formula for the distance from the incenter to the vertex:
$AB = c, BC = a$ and $AC = b$

$IB=\sqrt{\frac{(p-b).ac}{p}}=\sqrt{\frac{(56-b)600}{56}}=\sqrt{\frac{(56-b).75}{7}}$

but I don't know where to put the angles as they are not noticeable..and whether it is possible to solve by geometry?

Another idea:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Drop a perp from $I$ to $BC$ and say the foot of the perp is $H$. Then, $BH^2 = (AI - r) \cdot (AI + r) = AI^2 - r^2$ but $BH = AI \cos\theta$ where $\theta = 8^\circ$. Also use the formula $A = r \cdot p /2$ and $A = \frac{600}{2} \sin 2\theta$

Comment: The correct answer is very close to the official answer so it seems the official solution may have used some approximation to get to that nice looking answer.

Comment: @MathLover  what intrigues me is that the book gives the answer $15\sqrt2$...it's a value that seems to have not come from trigonometry...

Comment: @MathLover what intrigues me is that the book gives the answer 15\sqrt2...it's a value that seems to have not come from trigonometry...There is also the formula..$BI=\frac{a+c}{a+b+c} \cdot AT (T=BI \cap AC)$

Comment: @MathLover Maybe using the notable triangle and there can be another way out .. what do you think? (posted the drawing)

Comment: @petaarantes but with these angles, it is not a well known right  triangle and it is an approximation because $\arccos (7 / 5 \sqrt2) \approx 8.13^\circ$.

Comment: @MathLover It was just an idea...I also agree that it is unusual and not known to us but the book provides several right triangle relations and this is one of them...see that the solution provided was $15\sqrt2$ so I figured it out that this relationship was used

Comment: @ACB   itIt was just an idea ..see the comment for Math

Comment: @ACB  It is certainly not common but in Peruvian geometry many things are not common for geometry taught in schools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$BI=\frac{r}{\sin8^{\circ}}=\frac{\frac{2S}{a+b+c}}{\sin8^{\circ}}=\frac{ac\sin16^{\circ}}{(a+b+c)\sin8^{\circ}}=\frac{600\cdot2\cos8^{\circ}}{56}=...$$

So we did not get your answer.

Comment: ok...thanks for help..is it possible without trigonometry?

Comment: @peta arantes  Without trigo it's impossible because $\beta=16^{\circ}.$

Comment: If $BI=150/7\cdot \cos 8^\circ \approx15\sqrt{2}$, then $\cos 8^\circ\approx\frac{7}{5\sqrt{2}} \Rightarrow \cot 8^\circ\approx 7$. Maybe @petaarantes can use this fact??

Comment: Maybe using the notable triangle there can be another way out

Comment: complementing using the presented ratio of the triangle of $8^o$...$\frac{150.7}{7.5\sqrt2}=\frac{30}{\sqrt2} = 15\sqrt2$